# How to implement the page-objects ruby gem with selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, page-objects, ruby

I would like to use the page-objects gem in my selenium test projects, but before I can do that I need to get a small proof of concept project working so I can play around with it.

I have been following the [Get Started Now!](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Get-me-started-right-now!) guide on github, but for the life of me I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Admittedly, I am a ruby newbie and there is probably a very big "duh" moment coming up.

Here is my practice page.rb:

```
require 'page-object'

class SearchPage   
  include PageObject

  text_field(:searchBar, :id => 'q')  
  button(:submitSearch, :name => 'btnK')

  def search(query)
    self.searchBar = query
    submitSearch
  end

  def open()
    @browser.get 'https://www.google.com'
  end

  def close()
    @browser.close()
  end

end
```

And here is my practice test.rb:

```
require_relative 'page'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

class SearchPageTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_search_page
        @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
        search_page = SearchPage.new(@browser)
        search_page.open()
        search_page.search('page-objects')
        sleep 5
        search_page.close()
    end
end
```

This fails at line 10 in the test (search_page.search...) with the error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `text_field' for #Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x007fd37c1c1838

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Nates-MacBook-Air:Practice natesmith$ ruby test.rb 
Loaded suite test
Started
E
================================================================================
Error: test_search_page(SearchPageTest): NoMethodError: undefined method `text_field' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x007fe64d2c60d8>
/Users/natesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/page-object-2.2/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:1067:in `instance_eval'
/Users/natesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/page-object-2.2/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:1067:in `instance_eval'
/Users/natesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/page-object-2.2/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:1067:in `process_watir_call'
/Users/natesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/page-object-2.2/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:216:in `text_field_value_set'
/Users/natesmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/page-object-2.2/lib/page-object/accessors.rb:203:in `block in text_field'
/Users/natesmith/Desktop/Ruby/Practice/page.rb:10:in `search'
test.rb:10:in `test_search_page'
      7:         @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
      8:         search_page = SearchPage.new(@browser)
      9:         search_page.open()
  => 10:         search_page.search('page-objects')
     11:         sleep 5
     12:         search_page.close()
     13:     end
================================================================================


Finished in 2.875252 seconds.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.35 tests/s, 0.00 assertions/s
```

Help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the browser correctly open and navigate to https://www.google.com prior to the failure?

Comment: Yes the browser opens, and it appears to be navigating to the google homepage but quits before anything is visible

Comment: Could you include the stack trace? There are a number of possibilities, but I think if you give the stack trace I could probably figure out why it is erroring.

Comment: @SamWoods I have included them now in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like page-object is using the Watir implementation instead of the Webdriver implementation, and since Webdriver does not have a text_field property (while Watir does) it is failing.  I am not sure why it is trying to use Watir since your implementation matches the documentation for the page-object gem.  It looks like someone is having a similar issue with the latest version: https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/439. You might try using an older version of the page-object gem until that gets resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed the link to the issue and they have now resolved this issue. After updating the gem it is working as I would expect now